# Adapting Pandas Dataframes index with a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am working with different data sources and storaging each data in a different dataframe. I want to unify those dataframes in a big one but first I need to unify their indexes. Some of the dataframes' index follow the format YYYY-MM-DD, others do with YYYYTNN with n=1,2,3,4 and the last format is YYYYMNN with N from 01 to 12.

They represent the date, the period of 3 months in a year and the period of one month in a year. Mathematically is quite easy to transform all of them to the first format but I was sondering if there is some way to write in Python so that I do not have to change all my data indexes manually. The indexes are just pieces of text so I dont know how could I read the YYYYTN and detect the value of T for example.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: *Some of the dataframes' index, others ..*. Try `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)` on all of them?

Comment: In the ones with format YYYYMNN (1 value per month) I get an error with the code 'ParserError: minute must be in 0..59: 2021M02'. It works for the ones with the format YYYYTNN(4 values per year) but it writes the 4 values as one value per month for the first 4 months of the year and actually each value represents 3 months, so It should be something like 1st January, 1st April, 1st July and 1st October. Do you know how could I give that information in the command?

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve my issues. In case someone is interested this is what I did:

For those representing a period of 3 months I used datetime and timedelta to create a list of dates from the date where my data began until when it ended taking only 1st of January, April, July and October. The data for the first 3 months of the year was storaged as from the first of January and the other data was storaged the same way. After that I added the list as a new column to the dataframe in order to define it as the index. Here is the code.

```
def perdelta(start, end, delta):
curr = start
while curr < end:
    yield curr
    curr += delta
```

I did not write this code, I got it  from another question in this page but I can no longer find it.

```
Trim20052020=[]
for result in perdelta(date(2005, 1, 1),date(2020,12,1),relativedelta(months=3)):
Trim20052020.append(result)
```

This one creates the dates set for one data each three months from 2005 to the end of 2020.

```
df['index']=Trim20052020
df.set_index('index',inplace=True)
```

And finally defined it as the index.